# Sending an image with Dialogflow to Whatsapp user

Tags: json, twilio, dialogflow-es, chatbot, whatsapp

Since a few days I develop a chatbot for Whatsapp using Dialogflow, Twilio and Heroku to host my NodeJS server. I only use free services. 
What I want to do is to return a gif to a user. For example, the user sends a keyword and the chatbot returns a random gif from that word. In reading the documentation I found, I can't find the appropriate part of the JSON where I must insert the url of the gif to send. 
I would like to know how to do it or maybe it is not possible with the services I use ?

PS : Sorry for my English

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ppRuDTjf_E

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to tell what all things you have tried before posting the question so it makes answering the question better and precise.

Anyway you can do that by using Fulfillment. Just enable the Fulfillment in the Intent in which you want to send the image. Then go to Fulfillment on the left-menu and enable Inline Editor (you will need to add a billing account). Write the code for sending the image there.